# Error when initializing constant with 'this' | 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose

I have a file 'test.js' and I changed it's extension to `.ts`. What I'm really trying to do is to slowly migrate a `.js` codebase to typescript.

Now I'm getting the following error:

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.

This is the code:

```
animalSchema.pre('save', function save(next) {
  const animal = this;
  if (!animal.isModified('id')) {
    return next();
  }
  animal.name = "Test Animal";
  next();
  });
});
```

And this is my `tsconfig.js`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Type `this` as shown in the dupe

Comment: Not working for me... I'm using TS in the backend and that fix doesn't seem to work...